# Facing issue in HTTP module of Chilkat Library

Tags: request, chilkat, http-request

I am using Chilkat Library for making Http request. And Now I facing one issue that page response is most of time is null. Even page has data and that is not expired domain.

I have set MaxResponseSize to 0 but still the problem is same.

Please Guide me to solve this issue. And I also tried to make proxy request for solving this but none of then is working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check UserAgent, if the website see that you have a strange user agent they may refuse to output some content for you.